# Another add-in is using my custom ribbon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, outlook-addin

Good afternoon all!  Thank you in advance for any guidance you can offer.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 and C# to create an Outlook Add-In.  I have created a ribbon using the Ribbon Designer (named MainRibbon) and have it launching at run-time using the following code:

```
    // Load MainRibbon
    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility
    CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(
            new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new MainRibbon() }
        );
    }
```

The problem that I'm having is that my Outlook has a third-party add-in installed that also has its own ribbon.  When testing my ribbon, what happens is that my tab shows up on the ribbon as expected, but the third-party add-in tab is gone and the icons from that third-party add-in tab are merged into my custom ribbon.

I would ideally like the third-party add-in to keep its own tab and my ribbon to have its own tab. I am new to Visual Studio and going by the MSDN to create this and I see nothing about keeping my ribbon specific to just my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the VSTO Ribbon Designer will present you with a "shared tab" (usually labelled "Add-ins") that all customization may use. The philosophy is that this is better for the users...

You can (and should) add your own CUSTOM tab to the Ribbon in the Designer. No other Add-in will be able to share a custom tab created in the Designer.

Click in the Ribbon "bar", outside any tabs, then choose "Add Ribbon tab" from the context menu. In the Properties you can assign it a Name and a Label. You add buttons to it just like for the Built-in tabs.

Note: It is possible, using Ribbon XML, to expose a custom tab for sharing by providing a namespace and using qId. I mention this only for the sake of completeness...

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did it!